# ASP.NET MVC 3 routes with backbone views

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I'm pretty new to the web and am trying to understand what happens on our current project.  For one of our single page apps, the Controller returns a single view for the whole area.

```
[HttpGet]
[Url("admin")]
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(Admin);
}
```

In the actual Admin.cshtml, we create a backbone router that gets initialized for that section of the page and has the different views for that single page app section.  My question is, I want to create an action on the route

```
admin/import/upload
```

How would that look?  I don't want to actually return a View, but I want to call a function when that route gets hit to validate the uploaded file and return JSON info about the file.

Comment: Surely, if your using backbone to deliver views you need to separate that of from your .net code and use an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a model that has a property for your uploaded file like so, it should be of type `HttpPostedFileBase`.

```
public class UploadModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please choose a file to upload.")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to make your action that accepts the specified model and returns `JavaScript` instead of `View`.

```
public ActionResult Upload(UploadModel model)
{
    //only continue if the model is valid (i.e. all the required fields have been set)
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string json = "";//build your JSON here
        //return the JSON as a javascript response (with the correct headers, etc)
        return JavaScript(json);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    window.App = {
        Router: {}
        View: {}
    };

    App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            '*AreaName/admin/import/upload': 'upload'
        },

        upload: function() {
            var upload= new App.View.upload();
        },

    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.routes = new App.Router;
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
    });

})();
```